# Class and instance methods are both invoked by test, how could I "merge" them?

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck with this exercise from exercism.io:

**part of sum_of_multiples_test.rb**

```
...
  def test_sum_to_1000
    skip
    assert_equal 233168, SumOfMultiples.to(1000)
  end

  def test_configurable_7_13_17_to_20
    assert_equal 51, SumOfMultiples.new(7, 13, 17).to(20)
  end
...
```

**sum.rb**

```
class SumOfMultiples
  def initialize(*args)
    @args = args ||= [3,5]
  end

  def to(max)
    ary = []
    return 0 if max < 2
    @args.each do |m|
      for i in 0..max-1
        ary << i if i % m == 0
      end
    end
    ary.uniq!.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

If I use class method self.to, it can't see my instance variable @args, if I use
instance method "def to" first test don't pass. Is there a way to somehow "merge" both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another method to your class:

```
def self.to(max)
  new.to(max)
end
```

You can now call each of these and the result will be the same:

```
SumOfMultiples.to(1000)
SumOfMultiples.new.to(1000)
```